Magento 2 : Admin Panel “An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details”
yesterday I was in Admin Painel of Magento, but today when I tried to access it again, it says “An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.” I tried to setup:upgrade but I can’t run any command in the terminal it says: Class "Swissup\ Core\Helper\Component" not found#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Com
piled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-›create('Swissup\Core\He...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ \Compiled-›get ('Swissup\Core\He...')
#2 C: \xampp\htdocs \magento2 \vendor \magento \framework \ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled. php (150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
\Factory Compiled-›create('Swissup| (Core\ (Mo...')
#3 C: \xampp\htdocs \magento2\vendor\magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php (79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManagen
Factory\Compiled-›get ('Swissup) \Core\ \Mo...')
#4 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2 \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php (150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
\Factory\Compiled-›create ('Swissup\Corel\Mo...')
#5 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
Factory\Compiled-›get ('Swissup\ (Corel \Mo...')
#6 C: \xampp\htdocs \magento2 \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php (150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
Factory \Compiled-›create('Swissup||CorelICo...
#7 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor \magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php (125): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
(Factory\Compiled ›get('Swissup| \Corel\Co...')
#8 C: \xampp\htdocs magento2 vendor magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled-php(86): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager
Factory \Compiled->parseArray (Array)
#9 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2 \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager-php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Fac
tory\Compiled->create ('Magentol\Framewo...'
00 C: 0xamp hdoes magento2 vendor magento framework IConsole\C11 php (154) : Magento Framework ObjectManager \ObjectManager-›cr
eate ('Magento|\Framewo...')
#11 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(135): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli-›getApplicationComm
ands ()
#12 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony \console\Application.php (1286): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands(
#13 C: \xampp\htdocs \magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(631): Symfony\Component\Console\Application-›init()
#14 C: (xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(237): Symfony\Component \Console\Application-›find('setup:
upgrade')
#15 C: \xampp\htdocs \magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component \Console\Application->doRun(Obje
ct (Symfony\Component \Console\Input \ArgvInput), Object (Symfony\Component \Console\Output \ConsoleOutput))
#16 C: \xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component (Console \Input \ArgvInput), Object (Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application-›run()
#18 {main}
in the debug log says: main.CRITICAL: Error: Class “Swissup\Core\Observer\Backend\FetchNotifications” not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:121
This is what line 121 of AbstractFactory.php has: return new $type(...array_values($args));
Can someone please explain how to solve this error I need this solved for Thursday!

Try to run this command from CLI :
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/

After running this command still error there,
Then check this file :

Swissup\Core\Observer\Backend\FetchNotifications

Error from this file.

when I run any command it gives me that error

Which Error it give to you?
